# neo4j cypher query equivalent for gremlin filter and comparing its properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
g.V().hasLabel('Entity1').has('refSpecName','XYZ').where(__.in('Entity2').filter{it.get().value('prop1').getAt('AccessTechnology')=='ABC' && it.get().value('prop1').getAt('TargetSVLANProductType')=='Enhanced SLA'})

g.V().hasLabel('Entity1').has('deviceId',within(deviceIds)).filter{it.get().value('name').contains(name)}.as('entity1').out('Entity2').as('entity2').select('entity1','entity2')
```

1.iterates , get the object and get property of prop1 from object which is of map, using key get the value of map and compare against the provided string

2. iterates , get the object and get property of name from object which is of string and compare